# "abuse of which he was subjected" or "to which..."?

Tags: expression-choice

I am writing a paper and I can't figure out which of these is correct:

> "...the neglect and abuse of which he was subjected..."

or

> "...the neglect and abuse to which he was subjected..."

The second sounds a little less weird, but I would appreciate any help you guys might be able to provide.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to EL&U. The second one is correct. When someone ***is** the subject **of** something* we say that he *is **subjected to** it* or that *he is **the subject of** it*. Both terms are used but

> ...the neglect and abuse of which he was subjected...

mixes up the two ways of expressing the idea.

You can say:

> He was the subject of much abuse
>
> He was made the subject of much abuse

or

> He was subjected to much abuse

or even

> He was subject to much abuse

But you cannot say

> He was subjected of much abuse

The reason for this is that in

> *He was (made) the subject of much abuse*

the word *subject* is a noun and the phrase *of much abuse* is an adjectival phrase modifying *subject* but in

> *he was subjected to much abuse* and *he was subject to much abuse*

*subjected to* and *subject to* are tenses of the transitive phrasal verb *to subject to* and the word *abuse* is the object of that verb.

The easiest way to tell the difference is that the *noun* takes an article (a or the) but the *verb* does not.

For a definition of the noun see [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subject) and of the verb see [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subject%20to)

Note that in the first definition of the *noun* Merriam Webster use the *verb* as part of the definition!